# Azure Bot Channel Deployment with Azure CLI - not able to create bot channels

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-deployment, azureportal, azure-cli

I'm able to deploy Azure Bot registration channel using Azure CLI template

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-cli

But I can't figure out how to set Facebook Channel credentials for new-created channel in the same script.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-manage-channels

I can't find any informations in the official docs

Here is part of my deployment template:

```
{
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.BotService/botServices",
        "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
        },
        "kind": "[parameters('kind')]",
        "name": "[parameters('botId')]",
        "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
        "location": "global",
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('botId')]",
            "displayName": "[parameters('botId')]",
            "endpoint": "[variables('botEndpoint')]",
            "msaAppId": "[parameters('appId')]",
            "developerAppInsightsApplicationId": "[variables('insightsName')]",
            "developerAppInsightKey": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('insightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]",
            "enabledChannels": [
                "webchat",
                "directline",
                "facebook"
            ],
            "configuredChannels": [
                "webchat",
                "facebook"
            ]
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('insightsName'))]"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, currently we cannot find official docs explain how to define ARM template (script) for **Bot Channels Registration**. I try to find that part in **Automation script** on Azure portal, I find that `Microsoft.BotService/botServices` is not exported and included in the template.

[image]

> how to set Facebook Channel credentials for new-created channel in the same script.

I suspect that we cannot achieve that via ARM template at the moment. You had better to configure it on Azure portal.  Besides, you can give a feedback for your feature request on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureBot/issues) or [Azure Bot Service UserVoice site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/562027-azure-bot-service).

**Note:**

- This SO thread discussed a similar issue: [Automating Deployment in Bot Framework (Bot + LUIS+ QnA + Table Storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191957/automating-deployment-in-bot-framework-bot-luis-qna-table-storage)

Comment: Thanks for helping here. I post an issue on azure cli github repository https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5565

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Facebook channel with the Azure CLI.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bot/facebook?view=azure-cli-latest

```html
az bot facebook create --appid
                       --name
                       --page-id
                       --resource-group
                       --secret
                       --token
                       [--add-disabled {false, true}]
                       [--subscription]
```